# How to work with WCF methods which return dataset in dotne core?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

I must work with an external WCF service which is written in dotnet framework my project is dotnet core. one of methods in this service return dataset as result.
when I create the client of this service using vs2017 in a dotnet framework test project there is a method with this signature:

> Task<`DataSet`> SomeMethodAsync(int[] args)

but when I perform the same steps for creating soap client in dotnet core app this signature change to:

> Task<`SomeMethodResponse`> SomeMethodAsync(int[] args)

which **SomeMethodResponse** only has a **Result** Property with type **ArrayOfXElement**. in this **Result** we have 2 item. one for schema of result. and another for main data.

- now I want to know is there any way to generate the same signature?
- and if the answer is **NO**  how can I convert this result to a proccessable type like List or dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I Found an alternative solution. I generate class by this steps:

- Copy Schema part of the response to a file with name file.xsd.
- Open visual studio command prompt and execute this command **xsd file.xsd /classes**.
- add generated class to my solution.

and then use this code for parsing second part of result into generated class:

```
XSDGeneratedClass cls = new XSDGeneratedClass();
XmlSerializer xsr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XSDGeneratedClass));
var nodeString = dataset.openTempfllistResult.Nodes[1].LastNode.ToString();
cls = (NewDataSet)xsr.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nodeString)));
```

and *cls* now is filled with service data.